# View network devices on different subnet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, ethernet

I have my main router (192.168.1.1) connected to another router (second router) via ethernet (used as an access point 192.168.1.2) to extend my coverage. Other network devices are also connected to my second router via ethernet. I also have a Huawei WS322 mini router that is connected to the second router via ethernet, again to extend the range further. The problem is that my Huawei router has one WAN port no LAN ports. So I had to configure the router on a different subnet (192.168.15.x). When I connect any device to the 192.168.15.x network I can not see the network devices on the 192.168.1.x network. Is there a way around that or do I have to buy an access point to resolve this issue? I tried defining a static route from 192.168.15.x to 192.168.1.2 but that did not work.

Comment: are you talking about IP reachability, or a higher layer protocol like windows file sharing?

Comment: "The problem is that my Huawei router has one WAN port no LAN ports." Wrong: it has a 10/100/1000Mbps Ethernet RJ-45 port and an 802.11 b/g/n WiFi interface; it can run in Wi-Fi Router/Repeater/Client modes (taken from [Huawei's web-site](http://consumer.huawei.com/en/home-internet/connection-adapter/wifi-repeater/tech-specs/ws322-en.htm)). So you should not need new hardware.

Comment: IP reachability is not an issue. I want to play videos and music from my media server (DLNA).

Comment: @AFH I checked out all three setting. Router mode is what I currently have and explained in my post. Repeater mode is also pretty straight forward (you won't use the RJ-45 port) but I was never pleased with a repeater setup. I always felt performance was lacking. In client mode, it is quite similar to repeater mode, as far as I could tell. You scan for a wireless signal and connect your PC to the router for connectivity.

Comment: How did you define the static route, and on which device did you define it?

Comment: @Izam I defined the static route on my Huawei router. 192.168.15.x routes to 192.168.1.2.

Comment: its likely a firewalling/NAT issue with the Huawei router. you can try to forward ports, or entirely disable NAT, but I've seen few routers that let you fully disable it. Does the router support AP mode, so it disables NAT itself?

Comment: @Frank don't think I have the option to disable NAT. What ports should I forward? Unfortunately I do not have AP mode otherwise it would have solved my problem.

Comment: NBT ports are UDP\137,138,  and TCP\135, 139, 389, 445.